# PC component implementation (Compatibility specifically)

Tags: c#, .net

So, I'm writing an application for a community that helps users find compatible PC components (Or new PC components). So far I have a few classes implemented - Configuration for holding the currently selected components, such as Processor, Motherboard, GraphicsCard, and those classes themselves. Processor and Motherboard have, for example, an instance of the Enum SocketType = {LGA775, LGA1155...}. Now, I can think of a few implementations to check compatibility:

1. A single Compatibility class with functions that handle specific component compatibility. EG:
   isProcessorCompatible(Configuration config, Processor proc) handles any incompatibilities between a Processor and the current configuration. This I think is a pretty poor implementation as certain areas would need to be coded twice (Both SocketTypes for Processor and Motherboard, for example).
2. Expand the SocketType enumeration to a class that can check compatibility. What do I do for Voltage incompatibility between LGA1155 Processors and >1.5V RAM?
3. Just have a big list of rules that the program goes through every time. Add the component in to the Configuration before going through the rules, and remove it if it's incompatible. I think this would produce one massive method and it's quite messy, I don't like it.

Really what I'm asking, is there an alternative to these three suggestions previous, such that it's not messy, doesn't become an absolute pain to maintain, and actually works for values such as voltages?

Comment: Please don't put C# in the title.  That is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Just my point of view:
I would create something like a HardwareConfigurationManager class
that has a method

```
bool HardwareConfigurationManager.IsHardwareCompatible(IHardwarePart part1, IHardwarePart part2)
```

that accepts any hardware parts and find's an answer in db that you can organize in many ways :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I completely blanked on interfaces as I've been working almost exclusively with Haskell and Erlang the past year.

In fact, I do believe that something quite similar to this in the Configuration class could very well work the way I want it to, with only one part passed in and the subclass having access to the Configuration's members directly.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to research and implement the Open Closed principle in this case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Basically you want your code to be extensible to the point where adding new hardware doesn't break or require massive code changes to 10 classes just for it to be compatible with your current version.

You could achieve this by perhaps XML based configuration or a database and some very clever compatibility matching code.

Extending on Elasteps answer. Using `IHardwarePart`.

```
HardwareBasket hardwareBasket = new HardwareBasket();
hardwareBasket.Add(part1)
hardwareBasket.Add(part2)
hardwareBasket.Add(part3)
hardwareBasket.Add(part4)

bool compatible SystemConfiguration.IsHardwareBasketCompatible(hardwareBasket);
// better yet make the IsHardwareBasketCompatible return something like a 
// validation class that returns a yes/no for each item in HardwareBasket.
// this way you can report to the user that Nvidia 560Ti card is not compatible
// with their system but the other 3 components are.

CompatibilityResult compatible SystemConfiguration.IsHardwareBasketCompatible(hardwareBasket);
```

Where (or something like)

`public class HardwareBasket : List<IHardwarePart>`